# CustomListView in windows mobile 6.5.3

Tags: compact-framework, windows-mobile-6.5

I am using http://christian-helle.blogspot.in/2011/01/multi-platform-mobile-development_19.html for creating a custom list view.
In the existing sample it is not possible to pre set the selectedIndex of list view.

I have made few changes to the sample code and I am able to set the index and highlight it. but the problem is I am not able to set the scroll position to the highlighted item.
I have tried to set scrollBar.Value = itemindex, but it is not reflecting on the custom list  view.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be [ListView.EnsureVisible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.ensurevisible%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

```
private ListView listView1;

private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (-1 < listView1.SelectedIndex) {
    listView1.EnsureVisible(listView1.SelectedIndex);
  }
}
```